# I am trying to move my character with the arrow keys but it doesn't move

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I want to make my character move using the arrow keys, but it is not working and I have no idea why.

This is for an offline shooter game I'm trying to make. I have tried not using objects but this will soon become multiplayer so I don't want to make new files constantly.

Here is my code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var img = new Image();
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var Keys = {
  up: false,
  down: false,
  left: false,
  right: false
};
img.src = "images/char1.png";

let player = function player(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.speed = 5;
  this.health = 100;
};

window.onkeydown = function(e) {
  var kc = e.keyCode;
  e.preventDefault();

  if (kc === 37) {
    Keys.left = true;
  } else if (kc === 38) {
    Keys.up = true;
  } else if (kc === 39) {
    Keys.right = true;
  } else if (kc === 40) {
    Keys.down = true;    
  }
};

window.onkeyup = function(e) {
  var kc = e.keyCode;
  e.preventDefault();

  if (kc === 37) {
    Keys.left = false;
  } else if (kc === 38) {
    Keys.up = false;
  } else if (kc === 39) {
    Keys.right = false;
  } else if (kc === 40) {
    Keys.down = false;
  }
};

function move() {
  if (Keys.left) {
    x -= player.speed;
  }else if (Keys.right) {
    x += player.speed;
  }else if (Keys.up) {
    y -= player.speed;
  }else if (Keys.down) {
    y += player.speed;    
  }
}
function renderObject() {
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 32, 48, 0, 0, 32, 48);
}

function draw() {
  renderObject();
  move();
}

setInterval(draw, 10);
```

I expect the character to move when I press the arrow keys, but it doesn't move at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few issues:

1. You need to create a player object. At the moment your `player` function is simply just a "stencil" for your `player`. Instead, you need to create an instance of this object.

   `var player = new Player(x, y);`
2. You need to clear your canvas after each redraw, if you don't you will get a trail of images of your character:

   `ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);`
3. Draw your player image at the location of the player, not at `0, 0` each time:

   `ctx.drawImage(img, x, y, 32, 48);`

See working example below:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var img = new Image();
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var player = new Player(x, y);
var Keys = {
  up: false,
  down: false,
  left: false,
  right: false
};
img.src = "https://www.pinclipart.com/picdir/middle/366-3665375_deadpool-2d-video-game-characters-clipart.png";

function Player(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.speed = 5;
  this.health = 100;
};

window.onkeydown = function(e) {
  var kc = e.keyCode;
  if (kc === 37) {
    Keys.left = true;
  } else if (kc === 38) {
    Keys.up = true;
  } else if (kc === 39) {
    Keys.right = true;
  } else if (kc === 40) {
    Keys.down = true;
  }
};

window.onkeyup = function(e) {
  var kc = e.keyCode;
  if (kc === 37) {
    Keys.left = false;
  } else if (kc === 38) {
    Keys.up = false;
  } else if (kc === 39) {
    Keys.right = false;
  } else if (kc === 40) {
    Keys.down = false;
  }
};

function move() {
  if (Keys.left) {
    x -= player.speed;
  } else if (Keys.right) {
    x += player.speed;
  } else if (Keys.up) {
    y -= player.speed;
  } else if (Keys.down) {
    y += player.speed;
  }
}

function renderObject() {
  ctx.drawImage(img, x, y, 32, 48);
}

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  renderObject();
  move();
}

setInterval(draw, 10);
```

```html
<canvas height="120" width="400" id="canvas" style="border: 1px solid black;"></canvas>
```